# What Does This Script Do?

Tags: bash, scripting, dependencies, makefile

I'm reviewing the tutorial "Advanced Auto-Dependency Generation" and found a script with this:

```
 %.P : %.c
   ....; [ -s $@ ] || rm -f $@
```

What does that part of the target do?  I know I've seen this syntax:
`[...]||...` before in bash scripts, but I can't recall how it works exactly...

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: P.S. If I remember correctly $@ refers to the foo.P...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the preceding command fails (i.e. `[`), the following command is executed (`rm`). Failure is a non-zero return code.

Comment: Okay, but if I understand correctly, the `[ -s $@]` checks if foo.P exists... why remove it if it doesn't exist?? I'm confused...

Comment: It also checks that it's not empty. Maybe it's supposed to be empty.

Comment: @Jason: `[ -s $@ ]` tests if the target is non-empty. So if the `...` part produces an empty file, the rule will delete that file (but, curiously, succeed).

Answer (score 2):

The test `[ -s $@ ]` tests for a file that is not empty.

- If the file is not empty, do not remove it.
- If the file is empty, remove the (empty) file.

The sequence `[ -s $@ ] || rm -f $@` therefore removes the current target file (`$@` in `make` notation) if it is an empty file.

This is an interesting combination of shell and `make` notations.  The `$@` part is `make` notation for the target being built.  (It is also a shell notation for the complete list of arguments to a shell script, but in this context, the `make` notation takes precedence over the shell notation — the shell doesn't see `$@`.)